# Need for indefinite article "Anna ist Studentin: sie studiert Kunst"

Tags: grammaticality, article

I asked a cousin about her friend Anna in German and she responded:

> Anna ist Studentin: Sie studiert Kunst

But I thought this was grammatically incorrect due to a lack of an indefinite article:

> Anna ist eine Studentin: Sie studiert Kunst.

**Anna is a student. She studies art.**

Is she right with omitting the indefinite article? Why?

Comment: You don't say though, "she studies [an/the] art". Same difference, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example is one of the exceptions where German doesn't require an article. Some Grammars call this the *Nullartikel* (the "article that isn't there").

Substantives that denote *profession*, *function*, *nationality*, *descent*, *ideology* go without any article if expressing affinity to a group. This applies when the substantive stands in nominative and is tied with a form of *sein* or *werden* to the attributed nominative.

In short:

Occupation goes with no article.

> Sie ist Studentin
>
> Er ist Polizist
>
> Er war Sozialist

Comment: I'd say "may go without". The article is perfectly acceptable there, though rather meaningless. A source that says otherwise would be appreciated, if that's the case.

Comment: @vectory http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Ohne.html See "Angabe von Beruf, Herkunft,..." - The omission of the article is not optional, at least not in these generic examples. It may occur when you make it clear you mean a specific individual: "Mein Mann ist ein Arzt des Bundespräsidenten" vs. "Mein Mann ist Arzt".

Comment: Is that proscriptive? Deskriptively, it is certainly true, I wouldn't use an article there. But I don't see a good reason why it shouldn't be different, and it would probably not even raise any eyebrows, if anyone said it. "Sie ist 'ne Verkäuferin" is accepatable in my sociolect, I guess. Englisch *police* being a pluraletantum comes to mind, *he is police*, and "ich hab Polizei" (kennt der ein oder andere vielleicht) ;)

Comment: It's certainly, *Er ist **ein** guter Polizist* (except for Böhmermann, or in Kanaksprak, youth slang and whatnot), which the canoo link doesn't mention for "Berufe, Herkunft" ("Zugehörigkeit zu einer Gruppe"), as if that is a different thing, but does mention the same pitfall under "Abstrakta", as if that is a different thing The same doesn't apply to "Sammelbegriffe", though (chiefly "gutes Obst"). But: *Der Apfel ist das beliebteste Obst*.

Answer (score 3):

In German both variants are valid. They just transport a slightly different meaning:

> Anna ist Studentin

Anna is a person of `kind` Student: It describes her profession or any other property that makes her belong to a specific group of people.

Same would be:

> Anna ist Ärztin

or

> Anna ist Hundebesitzerin

Using the article you say that she es a `specific` entity of that group.

> Anna ist eine Studentin

Anna is one specific student.

I admit: The difference is very very small and I think almost every German speaker would use the two 100% interchangeable except probably authors who WANT to transport this litte difference in meaning.